# Atlassian Bamboo Rerun failed/incomplete jobs by command

Tags: api, rest, command, bamboo

For the failed Bamboo builds, I need to be able to use the "Rerun failed/incomplete jobs" using a **command** that can be triggered automatically. Currently, I can only do this by clicking on the Bamboo UI. As long as it can be used from a command it does not matter what mechanism is used (REST API, Python REST API, Curl, etc.). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation, you can use the API for this purpose, to be specific, the method [/queue/{projectKey}-{buildKey}-{buildNumber : ([0-9]+)}](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/5.5.0/#d2e859) using a PUT request.

> Continue partially done build. [...]

This is the use case your are looking for.

To the question, how to execute it from a command? You can use curl in the next way:

```
curl --user yourUser:passwordUser -X PUT "https://{yourBambooURL}/rest/api/latest/queue/planKey-buildNumber"
```

After executing above command, your build will start from the incomplete or failed jobs, same effect as "Rerun failed/incomplete jobs" button.